# Deleted Windows and installed Ubuntu 20.04. Internet is blazing fast then slows down and disconnects completely

Tags: networking, 20.04, internet

I'm on a Lenovo y740 Legion.

```
Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
```

***First 5 mins:***

```
sudo iwconfig
lo         no wireless extensions.

wls13      IEEE 802.11 ESSID: "C17H"
           Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.22 GHz Access Point: 43:CD:B2:54:9C:DE
           Bit Rate=866.7 Mb/s  Tx-Power=22 dBm
           Retry short limit:7  RTS thr:off  Fragment thr:off
           Encryption key:off
           Power Management:on
           Link Quality=59/70  Signal level=-51dBm
           Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0 Rx invalid frag:0
           Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:53  Missed beacon:0

en12       no wireless extensions
```

***After 10mins:***

```
sudo iwconfig
lo         no wireless extensions.

wls13      IEEE 802.11 ESSID: "C17H"
           Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.22 GHz Access Point: 43:CD:B2:54:9C:DE
           Bit Rate=234 Mb/s  Tx-Power=22 dBm
           Retry short limit:7  RTS thr:off  Fragment thr:off
           Encryption key:off
           Power Management:on
           Link Quality=64/70  Signal level=-46dBm
           Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0 Rx invalid frag:0
           Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:83  Missed beacon:0

en12       no wireless extensions
```

***30 mins passed from startup***

```
sudo iwconfig
lo         no wireless extensions.

wls13      IEEE 802.11 ESSID: "C17H"
           Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.22 GHz Access Point: 43:CD:B2:54:9C:DE
           Bit Rate=26 Mb/s  Tx-Power=22 dBm
           Retry short limit:7  RTS thr:off  Fragment thr:off
           Encryption key:off
           Power Management:on
           Link Quality=64/70  Signal level=-45dBm
           Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0 Rx invalid frag:0
           Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:109  Missed beacon:0

en12       no wireless extensions
```

***After 30 minutes:***

The connection rockets back up to around 400Mb/s. This cycle happens over and over again. I have no idea what is causing it or what I can do to maintain a stable connection.

Comment: For the purposes of diagnostics and process of elimination, I suggest that you try to connect to the 2.4Ghz network and also see if the problem persists when connected to Ethernet

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely due to an aggressive power-saving configuration in `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`. Try this:

Open the above system file:

```
sudo vi /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

You will see this:

```
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3
```

Change the `powersave` value from `3` to `2`.

Other possible values:

```
NM_SETTING_WIRELESS_POWERSAVE_DEFAULT (0): use the default value
NM_SETTING_WIRELESS_POWERSAVE_IGNORE  (1): don't touch existing setting
NM_SETTING_WIRELESS_POWERSAVE_DISABLE (2): disable powersave
NM_SETTING_WIRELESS_POWERSAVE_ENABLE  (3): enable powersave
```

Comment: Tried this. Didn't work. The strange cycling is something I've never experienced before. Just two days before I deleted windows on an Acer laptop and installed ubuntu 20.04 and it worked like a charm I haven't had a problem at all so I am dumbfounded as to why I am having such a hard time now.